# Periodically refresh Kotlin flow (polling)

Tags: kotlin, polling, kotlin-flow

How shoud I peridically "refresh" kotlin flow, to get fresh data.

I have list of book id's stored in room database. From network api I get the actual books using the stored ids.

My goal is to listen database changes and map the book ids to actual books. That works fine.

The problem is, how shoud I re-fetch periodically book data from network api but still keep listening the database all the time? So changes in book ids in database shoud allways trigger network api call (booksApi.get()).

```
fun getBookesFlow(): Flow<List<Book>> {
  return booksDao.all().map { ids -> 
    booksApi.get(ids)
  }
}

fun getPollingFlow(): Flow<List<Book>> {
  return flow {
    while(true) {
      // Reset the flow every 30 seconds
      getBookesFlow().collect { bookes -> // This is just idea, not working code
        emit(books)
      }
      delay(30.seconds)
    }
  }
}

fun getBooks(): {
  viewModelScope.launch {
   getPollingFlow().collect { books ->
    _uiState.update { it.copy( books = books) }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: why should id change trigger network call? why is id changing anyway?

Comment: Stored book id's are like user favourite books. When user adds book to favourite, I need to fetch the book details from api.

Comment: isn't it better to save the whole book model instead of just id? For users to add the book you already have requested the book details right, I would've just stored that model, what kind of dynamic data do your books contain that changes over time?

Comment: In my case books contain dynamic data which is short lived, it does not make sense (other than caching) to store them to db. At the time when user adds book to favourites, I do not have book details yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't force flows to provide values, so polling doesn't really apply to them. Instead, we create flows on top of other flows to provide the behavior we need.

In your case we need a flow that will observe `booksDao.all()` and then it will re-emit the same data periodically. We can do this easily with [transformLatest()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/transform-latest.html):

```kotlin
fun getBookesFlow(): Flow<List<Book>> {
  return booksDao.all()
    .transformLatest {
      while (true) {
        emit(it)
        delay(30.seconds)
      }
    }.map { ids -> 
      booksApi.get(ids)
    }
}
```

Whenever there is a new item to `booksDao.all()`, we start an infinite loop that emits the same data to the downstream flow. With each new item the previous loop is cancelled, so we only emit the latest.

Even better, we can create a flow operator that does the above:

```kotlin
fun getBookesFlow(): Flow<List<Book>> {
  return booksDao.all()
    .emitLatestPeriodically(30.seconds)
    .map { ids -> 
      booksApi.get(ids)
    }
}

fun <T> Flow<T>.emitLatestPeriodically(interval: Duration): Flow<T> = transformLatest {
    while (true) {
        emit(it)
        delay(interval)
    }
}
```

If you prefer to not use experimental functions (they're pretty stable though) then you can use [flatMapLatest()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can model this by treating both the database updates and also a 30 second timer as the sources of updates. To combine two flows, use [`combine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html).

```kotlin
private val timerFlow = flow {
    while (currentCoroutineContext().isActive)
    {
        emit(Unit)
        delay(30.seconds)
    }
}

fun getPollingFlow(): Flow<List<Book>> =
    timerFlow.combine(booksDao.all()) { _, ids ->
        booksApi.get(ids)
    }.distinctUntilChanged()
```

Comment: Note this solution does not reset the timer when new data from db arrives. If we receive the data from the network, then 28 seconds later we get new data in the db, we refresh the network, then we refresh again just 2 seconds later.